# あたまのいいところよ - Having ideas?

Tags: translation, verbs, expressions

I am reading some easy manga for kids as an exercise.
I am stuck on this sentence for quite some time and I would like an input on my translation :

- But how are we going to find it since we don't know where it is ? (that was easy to translate)
- そこがわたしのあたまのいいところよ。

This is how I tried to translate it :

> そこ

*the aforementioned place*

> わたしのあたま

*my head*

> のいいところよ

*the good place* (physical or I'm guessing here abstract)

So in the end I went with : *I have some ideas*.
Because I thought that *the head had some good points*.

Did I interpreted *あたまのいいところよ* correctly ? If I did why is there no verb ? (yes it is spoken and sometimes desu is implied but I don't know what verb should be used here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> そこがわたしのあたまのいいところよ。

"あたまのいい/頭のいい" is the same as "あたまがいい/頭がいい"; that is a set phrase meaning "someone is bright, intelligent, clever or smart"

The given phrase is very easy to understand for almost every Japanese, but it is quite difficult to rewrite it in plain Japanese in order to translate it into English.

The following sentences are my attempt rewritten in easy-to-understand Japanese.

(1) それが私が頭がいいことを示すものよ。
(2) それが私が頭がいいことを示す証拠{しょうこ}よ。
(3) それがどこだか分かることが、私が頭がいいことの証拠｛しょうこ｝よ。

My attemt in English:
(1) That's what shows/tells I'm smart.
(2) That's a proof that I'm smart.
(3) That I know where it is is a proof that I'm smart.
(3)' That I could guess where it is is a proof that I'm smart.

There is a phrase somewhat similar to the given one.

> それが私のいいところよ。

Literally, it will be like "That is my good point."
But the following interpretation will be the exact meaning of it.

> そのように振舞｛ふるま｝えるのが私の取柄｛とりえ｝/長所｛ちょうしょ｝よ。 *It's my advantage to be able to act like that*.

Answer (score 2):

あたまのいいところ is a relative clause. の in this case is actually が, because it is very common to replace が with の in relative clauses. So あたまがいいところ literally means "the place, where my head is good". The whole sentence literally means "That's where my head is good", which could be translated as "That's what I'm good at"